# git show content of file and LF or CRLF at the end of the file

Tags: git

I use the command

> git show sha1:/path/file > /c/tmp/file

When I open the file inside my repository with notepad++, I can see that the file is in DOS format.

When I open the file /c/tmp/file, the file is in Unix format, no matter what my core.autocrlf config is.

What should I do for the "git show" command to retrieve the file with the right autocrlf ?

Comment: It looks like `core.autocrlf` *is* working and the `LF` stored in the repo was converted to `CRLF` on Windows. As [the docs explain](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) `git show` shows the blob without any conversions: `For plain blobs, it shows the plain contents.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: If you have a modern Git, you can get Git to apply the text conversions: `git show --textconv` (or disable it explicitly with `git show --no-textconv`). The documentation does not say whether the default is enabled or disabled for `git show`, but peering at the current source (~Git 2.24) shows that it is enabled.

Comment: @torek  that's not what the OP did though. You could post this as an answer. The docs are ambiguous `For this reason, textconv filters are enabled by default only for git-diff[1] and git-log[1], but not for git-format-patch[1] or diff plumbing commands.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Aha: testing proves that `--textconv` *doesn't* apply the EOL conversions. It only applies an explicit `textconv` settings from `.gitattributes` (and then maybe only when doing diffs, which `git show` doesn't). However, `git cat-file --filters` does do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing (with Git 2.24.0) shows that:

```
git cat-file --filters HEAD:path/file
```

will apply CRLF filters (and presumably also smudge filters, but not `textconv` settings) to the object's content.  (Caution: see [Quential33's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808121/1256452) about *which* `.gitattributes` file content defines the filters that should be used.)  There does not seem to be a way to turn on `--filters` with `git show` (but there probably should be).

The `--filters` option was new in Git 2.11, introduced in [commit b9e62f6011](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9e62f60115c75c5be5de593862925c8b8d7e683) (author Johannes Schindelin).

Answer (score 2):

torek's answer is not entirely correct.

`--filters` will apply the filters (e.g. `.gitattributes`) that are **currently** in your working directory, not the `.gitattributes` at the **particular** HEAD or SHA1.

```sh
# show path/file at commit 4324a3, 
# but applying the .gitattributes currently present in your working directory.
git cat-file --filters 4324a3:path/file
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file#Documentation/git-cat-file.txt---filters

I do not think there is currently a way to show a file, while applying the filters from the historic `.gitattributes` at the particular commit; unless one checks out the commit and explicitly deletes and restores the file one is interested in (the delete and restore/checkout is necessary, for the filtering to actually run - e.g. for cases where a file was the same the whole time, but only the `.gitattributes` shifted `eol` from say `crlf` to `lf`, or the other way).

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-files --eol file` seems to give information on crlf status of the file.

From 'man git-ls-files':

> --eol
> Show <eolinfo> and <eolattr> of files. <eolinfo> is the file content identification used by Git when the "text" attribute is "auto" (or not set and core.autocrlf is not false). <eolinfo> is either "-text", "none", "lf", "crlf", "mixed" or "".
>
> "" means the file is not a regular file, it is not in the index or not accessible in the working tree.
>
> <eolattr> is the attribute that is used when checking out or committing, it is either "", "-text", "text", "text=auto", "text
> eol=lf", "text eol=crlf". Since Git 2.10 "text=auto eol=lf" and "text=auto eol=crlf" are supported.
>
> Both the <eolinfo> in the index ("i/<eolinfo>") and in the working tree ("w/<eolinfo>") are shown for regular files, followed by the ("attr/<eolattr>").

Comment: I think knowing the git meta-content to eol answers the question.  What git show does or doesn't do can be modified with external programs.  In particular, google sent me here to find just what git thinks a file eol convention is.  It is not  a direct answer to the  question, but is also an alternate way to modify what git show display.  Just pipe git show output to an eol translation engine.